# printing the cpus a task is allowed to run on?

Tags: linux-kernel, affinity, cpuset

I'm trying to printk the **cpus** that a specific task is allowed to run on.

Inside **struct task_struct** (which can be find [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=3.14)) there's the **cpumask_t cpus_allowed** which from what I understand contains exactly what Im looking for . 
Is that right ?

If so, how do I **extract** the cpus' numbers that are allowed ?

for example my comp has 8 logical cores - so Im expecting that somewhere inside **cpus_allowed** I can find those numbers (for example - 0,2,5)

Comment: Given that it's a `cpumask_t`, I suspect that it is an integer (either 32- or 64-bit) that contains a 1 bit in each position if the corresponding CPU is allowed. In other words, it's not a list of numbers, but you'll have to iterate over the bits and test each one.

Answer (score 1):

Macro `for_each_cpu` will iterate over all CPU's, allowed by the given mask:

```
// Assume `mask` is given.
int cpu;
for_each_cpu(cpu, mask)
{
    printk("Allowed CPU: %d\n", cpu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a function inside the kernel that does exactly what I needed in [cpumask.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/cpumask.h?v=3.14) **cpumask_scnprintf**:

```
 /**
 * cpumask_scnprintf - print a cpumask into a string as comma-separated hex
 * @buf: the buffer to sprintf into
 * @len: the length of the buffer
 * @srcp: the cpumask to print
 *
 * If len is zero, returns zero.  Otherwise returns the length of the
 * (nul-terminated) @buf string.
 */
static inline int cpumask_scnprintf(char *buf, int len,
                                    const struct cpumask *srcp)
{
        return bitmap_scnprintf(buf, len, cpumask_bits(srcp), nr_cpumask_bits);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `cpumask_pr_args()` defined inside [cpumask.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cpumask.h).

Usage:

```
 printk("%*pbl\n", cpumask_pr_args(mask));
```

See [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/core-api/printk-formats.html) for information about the `%*pbl` placeholder.